# ConvertFrom-String returns System.Array that can't be viewed in tabular form

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to parse the results from a whois command performed in bash into a powershell object. However the resulting `$obj` doesn't behave how I would expect and I am unsure why.

The `$obj` is generated as follows:

```
$domain = "domain.uk"

$whoisResult = bash -c "whois $domain"

$template = "@
        Domain name:
        {Domain:domain.uk}

    Data validation:
        {Validation:Nominet was not able to match the registrant's name and/or address against a 3rd party source on 29-Jan-2016}

    Registrar:
        {Registrar:RegistryGate GmbH [Tag = REGISTRYGATE-DE]}
        {RegistrarURL:URL: http://www.registrygate.com}

    Relevant dates:
        Registered on: {RegistrationDate:29-Jan-2016}
        Expiry date:  {ExpiryDate:29-Jan-2019}
        Last updated:  {LastUpdated:28-Jan-2018}

    Registration status:
        {Status:Registered until expiry date}.

    Name servers:
        {NameServer*:dns.dns1.de}
        dns.dns2.de
        dns.dns3.de
        dns.dns4.de

    WHOIS lookup made at {TimeStamp:18:09:22 11-Jul-2018} 
@"

$obj = $whoisResult | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $template
```

When I attempt to view this object in a tabular view it only shows the domain property. If I view it using `Format-List` then it shows all the properties, but separated by spaces.

Lastly I have noticed that `TimeStamp` is completely missing from the template.

So my questions are

1. Do I need to escape `:` in the template?
2. How do I modify the resulting object so that I can view it in tabular form?
3. `$obj` shows as `System.Array`, is this correct, should it be an array?

Thank you in advance, this is my first foray into parsing more complex output from strings, so if there is a better way then I'm also open to changing my approach.

```
PS C:\Users\jacob> $obj

Domain   
------   
domain.uk














PS C:\Users\jacob> $obj | ft

Domain   
------   
domain.uk














PS C:\Users\jacob> $obj | fl


Domain : domain.uk

Validation : Nominet was not able to match the registrant's name and/or address against a 3rd party source on 29-Jan-2016

Registrar : RegistryGate GmbH [Tag = REGISTRYGATE-DE]

RegistrarURL : URL: http://www.registrygate.com

RegistrationDate : 29-Jan-2016

ExpiryDate : 29-Jan-2019

LastUpdated : 28-Jan-2018

Status : Registered until expiry date

NameServer : dns.dns1.de

NameServer : dns.dns2.de

NameServer : dns.dns3.de

NameServer : dns.dns4.de




PS C:\Users\jacob> $obj.getType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                      
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                      
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array                                                                                                  

PS C:\Users\jacob> $obj | gm -Force


   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name        MemberType   Definition                                                                                                                                      
----        ----------   ----------                                                                                                                                      
pstypenames CodeProperty System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] pst...
psadapted   MemberSet    psadapted {ToString, Equals, GetHashCode, GetType}                                                                                              
psbase      MemberSet    psbase {ToString, Equals, GetHashCode, GetType}                                                                                                 
psextended  MemberSet    psextended {Domain}                                                                                                                             
psobject    MemberSet    psobject {BaseObject, Members, Properties, Methods, ImmediateBaseObject, TypeNames, get_Members, get_Properties, get_Methods, get_ImmediateBa...
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)                                                                                                                  
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()                                                                                                                               
GetType     Method       type GetType()                                                                                                                                  
ToString    Method       string ToString()                                                                                                                               
Domain      NoteProperty string Domain=domain.uk
```

Output from `$whoisResult`

```
PS C:\Users\jacob> $whoisResult

    Domain name:
        domain.uk

    Data validation:
        Nominet was not able to match the registrant's name and/or address against a 3rd party source on 29-Jan-2016

    Registrar:
        RegistryGate GmbH [Tag = REGISTRYGATE-DE]
        URL: http://www.registrygate.com

    Relevant dates:
        Registered on: 29-Jan-2016
        Expiry date:  29-Jan-2019
        Last updated:  28-Jan-2018

    Registration status:
        Registered until expiry date.

    Name servers:
        dns.dns1.de
        dns.dns2.de
        dns.dns3.de
        dns.dns4.de

    WHOIS lookup made at 11:40:09 12-Jul-2018

-- 
This WHOIS information is provided for free by Nominet UK the central registry
for .uk domain names. This information and the .uk WHOIS are:

    Copyright Nominet UK 1996 - 2018.

You may not access the .uk WHOIS or use any data from it except as permitted
by the terms of use available in full at https://www.nominet.uk/whoisterms,
which includes restrictions on: (A) use of the data for advertising, or its
repackaging, recompilation, redistribution or reuse (B) obscuring, removing
or hiding any or all of this notice and (C) exceeding query rate or volume
limits. The data is provided on an 'as-is' basis and may lag behind the
register. Access may be withdrawn or restricted at any time.
```

Comment: IMO this questsion is too broad. To my experience the results of `ConvertFrom-String` with `-TemplateContent` are not the best (also your template doesn't match the data I get with whois at all). Better parse yourself with [these strings](https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/approved-with-specs-2013-09-17-en#whois)

Comment: Depending on the registrar involved the output (keywords) can be quite different, also comments (sometimes with a leading `%` sometimes trailing after a `>>>` also is the information sometimes indented (see `stackoverflow.com` vs. `1und1.de`)

Comment: I'm only looking at .uk domain, which consistently returns this output format currently, but I appreciate that different registrars/TLD's return information in different formats, and in some cases, structure completely differently. My main query is how I can reformat / refactor my output in the snippet above.

Comment: Agree with above comment regarding `ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent` seems very fragile, or has too many problems, because each time I tried using it, I gave up and parsed in a different manner.